# Xcode-like navigation panes/drawers

Tags: xcode, menu, floating, sliding, drawer

I was wondering what Apple used to develop the sliding drawer menus found in XCode's GUI itself. For example the debug, navigation, and utility areas may be toggled.

For example..
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Certainly I could easily resize and move the views in code to create the (expensive) show/hide animation, I was just wondering if anyone knew of an EXISTING cocoa library item that mimics this show/hide functionality. Something like iPad's SplitViewController with hiding ability for one of the views. My target application is for OS X. Much obliged.

Similar topic w/solution but not sure if they're talking about the same concept:
[how do i create a sliding menu in xcode iphone like the main android menu sliding menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872407/how-do-i-create-a-sliding-menu-in-xcode-iphone-like-the-main-android-menu-slidin)

PS I would also be thrilled with floating/dockable menus (ex, photoshop, visual studio)